# make: have built target; make install : *** No rule to make target 'install'

Tags: cmake, makefile

In Ubuntu20.04.
I want to insatll **easy3d**, but I can not make install it successfully.
make

```sh
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easy3d.dir/surface_mesh_io_obj.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easy3d.dir/surface_mesh_io_off.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easy3d.dir/surface_mesh_io_ply.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easy3d.dir/transform.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libeasy3d.a
[100%] Built target easy3d
```

And the build have files:

```sh
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  Makefile  cmake_install.cmake  libeasy3d.a
```

Then I excute the command **make install**, I got

```sh
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

How could I fix it

Comment: It seems the project doesn't support installation at all.

Comment: ... which is weird, especially given that they provide instructions for using it in other packages, and those depend on easy3d in fact being installed or otherwise discoverable.  My educated guess based on other aspects of the documentation is that the maintainers anticipate that the provided build system will be used only within the context of an IDE that understands CMake, and which either obviates the need for installation or makes its own provision for that.  If so, then that's not very impressive.

Answer (score -1):

I made a big mistake that is nothing to install.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).